# Make a clickable link with onclick but without href=#?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of clickable identifiers on my page. About hundred, like 'cat1', 'cat2', 'dog1', 'dog2', 'dog3' etc. Then I have a `function IDClick(id) {}`

I need those identifiers clickable in HTML, to achieve that I used `<a>` tag with `onclick`

```
<a onclick=IDClick(id)>id</a>
```

now it works, but the cursor will not change when it is hovered over the clickable element.

So I try to add `href=#`

```
<a href=# onclick=IDClick(id)>id</a>
```

Now the cursor is OK, but when I click the item, the URL in the browser location bar will change. This is not desired.

How to get the mixed behavior?

I do not need underline as well.

Comment: You're missing quotes on your attributes.

Comment: @SuperScript: Quotation marks are optional in HTML, if the attribute value doesn't contain a space (and maybe `>`).

Comment: @FelixKling : It's still cleaner.  I wasn't suggesting that that was the error.

Comment: This is just an example, actual code looks like this `<a href=# onclick=IDClick("'+animals[0]+animal+'")>'`

Comment: @SuperScript: Well, it sounds like you were though.

Comment: *"I do not need underline as well."* You can change the link's style with CSS.

Comment: But, if you don't want to link to a difference resource anyway, use a `button` instead.

Comment: that was my first thought! but so many `button`s make me feel dizzy, so I switched to `a`

Comment: Thank you for your question, I needed to know about the "return false" trick for changing tabs with a link in the same page.  You helped me out.  Thanks.

Comment: This is very old, but be aware that your example in the comment above looks like it could be susceptible to XSS --- what happens if, e.g., `animal` were `'+alert('hello, world!')+'`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use CSS to force the cursor to change on hover of the clickable element:

```
.myClickableThingy {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And then you can switch back to `<span>`s or whatever of element you were using before `<a>` tags.

Comment: what does it mean "Switch back to whatever element types you were using before tags"?

Comment: My apologies. I was unclear. I meant use divs or spans instead of anchor elements.

Comment: I tried divs, but they will span across whole page and making them auto-sized seems a too complicated task.

Comment: Spans should do it then. Or the other solutions proposed that abort the default behavior. You have several options.

Comment: Using CSS makes it *look* ok, but still leaves it inaccessible from the keyboard. (Ie, tab will never focus the link.)

Answer (score 77):

You need to stop the browser from doing it's default action.

```
<a href="#" onclick="IDClick(id);event.preventDefault();">id</a>
```

When you click on a link, the default action is to go to that address.  `event.preventDefault();` prevents the browser from doing the default action.

This is a significantly better solution for accessibility. Quoting [@aij's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165590/make-a-clickable-link-with-onclick-but-without-href/20165626?noredirect=1#comment59956912_20165637): "using CSS makes it look ok, but still leaves it inaccessible from the keyboard (ie, tab will never focus the link)".

Comment: I think this one is better than approved answer because you don't need manipulate css

Comment: I'd put the `preventDefault` call in the click handler function, but  otherwise, this is a much better solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer because the browser will show the url somewhere like at the bottom left which is something many people are used to.

Comment: This works. Thx. I am just wondering, if there is in 2023 is there not a better way instead of adding ``event.preventDefault();`` behind each onclick event ❓

Answer (score 6):

Give your anchor element a class and style it to achieve what you need:

```
<a class='kinda-link' onclick='whatevs()'>Hi I'm a kinda-link</a>
```

And your css:

```
a.kinda-link:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: This won't let you tab to the element/give it focus.

Comment: @SuperScript was that a requirement in the OP question?

Comment: No, just an accessibility problem.  It'll work, just not really best practice.

Comment: @SuperScript yeah but I don't think he needs a anchor in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Recently I use clickable **spans** in most cases.

```html
    Some text with some
<span onclick="alert('hey there')"
         style="color: blue; cursor: pointer">part</span>
that is clickable.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `return false;` in the IDClick handler function.

`<a href=# onclick=IDClick(id)>id</a>`

```
IDClick() {

   ...
   return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `href='javascript:IDClick(id)'` then it will work as expected AND show the desired cursor behavior.